# how to create a program application in MacOS that is shareable

Tags: python, macos, executable

So I have developed a python script which opens Slack app (which is based on Chromium) with a remote-debugging-port, and then injects a JavaScript bundle.  Ideally I'd like to instead make a shell script which called the python file (and checked if python was available in the right version etc!) first.

This however would require the user to call the shell script from the terminal

What I'd *really* like would be a single executable file that contains:

- the `.sh` script file
- the `.js` bundle that gets injected
- the `.py` file that the script calls
- bonus, an icon that would show for the program in MacOS

It's been great developing the proof of concept so far, but creating an application is a new step to me.  What is a way to create a (double)clickable file that contains the 4 files above and doesn't need to live in a terminal tab?  Thanks

PS. This will always remain a simple app so simplicity is probably a key consideration.

Comment: Those go in an app package, not an executable.

Comment: Your term `app package` + MacOS led me to [here|https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631926/how-to-generate-an-installer-package-for-mac-app] on SO so thanks, it's probably enough to decide on an approach and link to which I decide to use.